# history command buffer in MATLAB - call by command number

Tags: matlab

Can I call a command from matlab history by its number, pretty much in the same fashion as in  unix/linux

```
!10
```

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to access the command history programmatically using java.

```
javaHistory=com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
```

If you want to evaluate the 10-th command in the history, you'd run

```
eval(javaHistory(10).toString)
```

Comment: Well look at that, there is a way. +1