# Recall Matlab History with Multiline-Command

Tags: matlab, command-line, history, line

I have a command in the command line of Matlab which is longer than just one line but when recalling it by pressing arrow-up, I just can go through every single line of the multiline-code... Is there a way to recall the complete last execution, no matter if just single or multiline?!
thanks!

Comment: related questions: [How do I search through MATLAB command history?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5053692/97160), [history command buffer in MATLAB - call by command number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4405536/97160)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Command History window, highlight the relevant lines and press F9 (or right-click and select Evaluate Selection if your shortcuts differ from mine).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to right click the particular line in the command history window and select `Copy` or `Evaluate Selection` :)

[image]

If you'd like to copy a significant portion of your history, then you can output the contents of your history file (which is stored in `history.m` in the preferences directory) to the command window and copy from there.

```
type([prefdir '/history.m'])

%-- 20/6/11 3:17 PM --%
clc
outputVariable=someVeryLongFunctionNameThatMakesNoSense(inputVar1,'inputString1',inputVar2)
type([prefdir '/history.m'])
```

The above command and the screenshot were on a Mac. As always, be careful with the `/` on Windows. I can never remember which way it leans...

Comment: One can write a function that reads the history file: `fullfile(prefdir,'history.m')` and extract the last command, continuously testing the previous line to check if it ends with the characters `...`, then combining all of them appropriately and returning the resulting string

Comment: @Amro, @yoda: It's much simpler to access the history directly: `javaHistory=com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory; lastCommand = javaHistory(end).toCharArray';`

Comment: @Jonas: Nice, I knew there was an undocumented feature to access the command history, just couldn't find it myself :)